# How do I change the back button image in stack navigator in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator, react-native-stylesheet

How can I change the image of the back button in React Native?

[image]

I want to change the back arrow to a chevron.

Answer (score 0):

In your StackNavigator, provide the screenOptions prop with `headerBackImageSource` set to the back arrow icon or image you want.

```
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerBackImageSource: `...image source...`
      }}
    >
```

Comment: The documentation is pretty self explanatory: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#customizing-the-back-button

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: make sure your image is the right url. you need to provide detail on what you tried

Comment: I've tried and it still doesn't work

Comment: I put the same thing as the code you posted with a bit more screen options and I provided the headerbackimagesource with https://brandeps.com/icon-download/C/Chevron-left-icon-vector-18.svg

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@georgestoy2008/the-cancer-app is the link for my project

Comment: I haven't been able to take a closer look, but have you considered the fact that you're using a black icon against a black background?

Comment: Change the background color to white then and see

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle the default header of stack navigator is by creating a custom one. Every component in the main stack exports a back method so you can use it to create a event listener for your custom arrow like in the example below.

MAIN COMPONENT:

```
function Home({ navigation }) {

  return(
    <>
       <CustomHeader
         title="Home Page"
         handleBack={() => {
           navigation.goBack()
         }}
       />  
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

CUSTOM HEADER COMPONENT:

```
function CustomHeader(props) {
  const title = props.title

  const handleBack = () => {
    props.handleBack()
  }

  return(
    <View>
      <Pressable
        onPress={handleBack}
      >
        <Image
          source={backArrowIcon}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </Pressable>
      <Text>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default CustomHeader
```

You just need to style that and import all the components like View, Text, CustomHeader etc.